# run function only if condition

Tags: php, function, if-statement

i want to run this function only if the current logged in user is the post author

```
global  $user_ID;
$admin_user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_ID );
$selected   = empty( $post->ID ) ? $user_ID : $post->post_author;

function return_custom_price( $post ) {
global $post;
$new_total = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_total_egp', true);
$price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_regular_price', true);
//$sale_price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price', true);
$now_price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_price', true);
$woo_usd_rate = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_usd_rate', true);
$woo_price_usd = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_price_usd', true);
$cog = $woo_price_usd * $woo_usd_rate;

if($user_ID == $selected ){

update_post_meta($post->ID, '_regular_price', $new_total);
update_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price', '');
update_post_meta($post->ID, '_price', $new_total);
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wc_cog_cost', $cog );

}
}

add_action('save_post', 'return_custom_price');
```

this is what i've tried but it isn't working, and it ran anyway

what i'm trying to do is that 
when users post to wordpress using woocommerce from frontend, the posted post is added to wordpress in draft state, and admins just publish/approve the posts

what's happening right now is that in anyway if the admin clicked on publish the function runs and updates the post metas, i don't want to update the post metas unless if the admin who publish the post is the current owner/author of the post, and if the admin who approve/publish the post is not the post author, the post just get published without any metas updates

Comment: It seems like ur $post->ID never comes empty. You need to look for some other field.

Comment: Put your var_dumps() here and I suggest you to avoid globals for god's sake.

Other thing: Your routine has a security flaw, if do you want to update post only if the user is the author, if the post->ID doesn't exists you need to terminate the routine, not pass by.  Get your $user_ID out of $select ternary.

Comment: i need globals, cause i'm outside of the loop

Answer (score 0):

ok the solution was in the sequence of calling the action, and the save_post runs on updating the post anyway without applying any checks

so this can be a solution

```
function return_custom_price( $post ) {
global  $post;
$market = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'market', true);
if($market == "" ){
    return;
}
$new_total = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_total_egp', true);
$price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_regular_price', true);
//$sale_price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price', true);
$now_price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_price', true);
$woo_usd_rate = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_usd_rate', true);
$woo_price_usd = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_price_usd', true);
$cog = $woo_price_usd * $woo_usd_rate;

update_post_meta($post->ID, '_regular_price', $new_total);
update_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price', '');
update_post_meta($post->ID, '_price', $new_total);
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wc_cog_cost', $cog );
}   
add_action('save_post', 'return_custom_price');
```